# How to group users by email in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I wonder how can I query username base on its email address:

I have one table called **users**:

```
username    email
AAAA        A@A1.com
BBBB        B@B1.com
CCCC        C@C1.com
DDDD        D@A1.com
.....
```

And one table called **company**:

```
company    domain
ComA       A1.com
ComB       B1.com
ComC       C1.com
```

Any simple query can get all usernames which has email domain listed in company table?

Comment: That is a simple join. Please take a SQL tutorial to learn the very basics

Comment: At first you should try to normalize your DB.

Comment: @juergend Could you show me how to choose condition for joining these two tables?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: What is not normalized here?

Comment: your question is not clear. it odes not state what you need clearly, or things you need clearly.

Comment: @juergend, IMHO As the `domain` is part of the application domain the `email` is not atomic for me.

Comment: So you would design a table having a email address that is part name and part reference to a list of domains? Come on...

Comment: @juergend, It depends..., If DB more static I would do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the below query..

```
   Select username,email ,domain,company
   From users
      join company 
        On email like '%@' || domain
```

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful.

Comment: You are always welcome.. And thank you @Gordon Linoff for the edit.. :)

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for help.